# Parameter passing between actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried this:

```
public ActionResult Index() // << it starts here
{
    return RedirectToAction("ind", new { name = "aaaaaaa" });
}

[ActionName("ind")]
public ActionResult Index(string name)// here, name is 'aaaaaaa'
{
    return View();
}
```

and it works..

so, I tried this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string cnpj) // starts here
{
    List<Client> Client = db.Client // it always find one client
        .Where(c => cnpj.Equals(c.Cnpj))
        .ToList();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", Client); // client is not null
}

public ActionResult Index(List<Client> Client) //but when goes here, client is always null
{
    if (Client != null)
        return View(Client);

    return View(db.Client.ToList());
}
```

Why it happens? Is there something wrong with the second code block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass only primitive types in redirect, you can use the `TempData` for complicated types.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string cnpj) // starts here
{
    List<Client> Client = db.Client // it always find one client
        .Where(c => cnpj.Equals(c.Cnpj))
        .ToList();

    TempData["client"] = Client;  //<=================
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Client = TempData["client"];  //<=================

    if (Client != null)
        return View(Client);

    return View(db.Client.ToList());
}
```

Basically `TempData` is just like saving data in the `Session` but the data will be deleted automatically in the end of the request where it was read.

`TempData` on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx)

**Notes:**

- The common naming convention in `C#` defined private variable to be camel-case. 
  `client` instead of `Client`.
- For `List<Client>` variable I would use `clients` as a name instead of `client`.
- You should use a resource for the `"client"` string so it won't get out of sync, meaning one method puts the data in `"Client"` while the other looking for it in `"client"` or `"Client Data"`

Comment: It bears mentioning that these are vastly different approches to passing the data around. Using the temp data provider by default will store the data in the session. Also, temp data is not guaranteed to be there when you get back. Might consider executing the action rather than a redirect instead if it is important--on that topic, is a POST necessary here? Search results are usually better handled with GET...

Comment: @Paul. I think I mentioned it in the answer, but thanks for clarifying the drawbacks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your issue is that you are passing client as the parameter, but what your action method expects is an object containing a property "Client". Alternatively, it would work as you've written it if there is a route definition that specifically asks for a client parameter.

Comment: Where did you see a _"method expects to object containing a property "Client" "_ I  haven't!